# SUM not calculating correctly with UNION - MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Could anyone point out where my sql query is wrong, it doesn't give the desired result regarding the SUM when i fetch the data?

I am trying to calculate the first 5 VAR_MEASURE_1 results of each union, for the first union i should be getting -7.00 but I'm getting 4.00.

EDIT - here is the data before I use the sum query-

```
                VAR_MEASURE_1
16587   SBEN    -14.000 0.000   2014-09-30 00:31:24
16288   SBEN    3.000   0.000   2014-09-30 00:52:46
16288   SBEN    3.000   0.000   2014-09-30 00:53:59
16006   SBEN    5.000   0.000   2014-09-30 01:16:36
15271   SBEN    -4.000  0.000   2014-09-30 01:40:09
15786   SBEN    -6.000  0.000   2014-09-29 00:15:02
16097   SBEN    2.000   0.000   2014-09-29 00:17:34
16097   SBEN    2.000   0.000   2014-09-29 00:19:25
15771   SBEN    -9.000  0.000   2014-09-29 00:38:49
16155   SBEN    7.000   0.000   2014-09-29 01:13:26
15661   SBEN    -9.000  0.000   2014-09-28 17:40:05
14425   SBEN    1.000   0.000   2014-09-28 17:49:09
14425   SBEN    1.000   0.000   2014-09-28 17:50:24
15657   SBEN    -9.000  0.000   2014-09-28 18:02:09
15655   SBEN    -14.000 0.000   2014-09-28 18:24:31
```

Here is it after

```
                             SUMA
15276   Sample 1    SBEN     4.000  2014-09-30 00:31:24
15855   Sample 2    SBEN    -77.000 2014-09-29 02:40:56
15661   Sample 3    SBEN    -109.000    2014-09-28 17:40:05 







$sql = "(SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE, SUM(VAR_MEASURE_1) AS SUMA  FROM LIVE_VARCOLL WHERE doe between '2014-09-30 00:00:00' AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59' AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN' LIMIT 5)
    UNION
    (SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE, SUM(VAR_MEASURE_1) AS SUMA FROM LIVE_VARCOLL WHERE doe between '2014-09-29 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-29 23:59:01' AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN'
    ORDER BY doe LIMIT 5)
    UNION
    (SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE, SUM(VAR_MEASURE_1) AS SUMA FROM LIVE_VARCOLL WHERE doe between '2014-09-28 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-28 23:59:01' AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN'
    ORDER BY doe LIMIT 5)
    UNION
    (SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE, SUM(VAR_MEASURE_1) AS SUMA FROM LIVE_VARCOLL WHERE doe between '2014-09-27 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-27 23:59:01' AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN'
    ORDER BY doe LIMIT 5)
    UNION
    (SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE, SUM(VAR_MEASURE_1) AS SUMA FROM LIVE_VARCOLL WHERE doe between '2014-09-26 00:00:01' AND '2014-09-26 23:59:01' AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN'
    ORDER BY doe LIMIT 5);";
```

Comment: and the "desired result" is: ..?

Comment: The first row for SUMA should be -7.00 but I'm getting 4.00

Comment: I'm sure SUM is calculating correctly.

Comment: Geeez, I should have guessed! (Seriously, do provide some data and expected results, not _"the answer should be -7"_)

Comment: load your data to sqlfiddle

Comment: Put UNION ALL if you want duplicated rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misintepretting the way of how `SUM()` works.

`SUM()` does not limit itself to `LIMIT` - `LIMIT` only tells sql how many rows you want to get in the result. So in your case each `UNION` part has the SUM of all rows fulfilling the requirements, not only the first five of them.

If you want to select the sum of the first five rows of a table, that meet certain conditions, you should do it like in the folllowing example. The subquery retrieves only five rows, and then the outer query is able to sum it up.

**To be clear - this is the SQL to retrieve the data only of the first part** of your UNIONed query. You could try and build your other `UNION` parts like that:

```
SELECT tmp.*, SUM(tmp.VAR_MEASURE_1) as SUMA 
   FROM (
      SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE
      FROM LIVE_VARCOLL 
      WHERE doe between '2014-09-30 00:00:00' 
         AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59' 
         AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' 
         AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN' 
      ORDER BY doe
      LIMIT 5 
   ) tmp
```

So your UNIONs should look like this:

```
(SELECT tmp.*, SUM(tmp.VAR_MEASURE_1) as SUMA 
    FROM (
       SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE
       FROM LIVE_VARCOLL 
       WHERE doe between '2014-09-30 00:00:00' 
          AND '2014-09-30 23:59:59' 
          AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' 
          AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN' 
       ORDER BY doe
       LIMIT 5 
    ) tmp)
UNION
(    SELECT tmp.*, SUM(tmp.VAR_MEASURE_1) as SUMA 
    FROM (
       SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, CONTRACT_CODE
       FROM LIVE_VARCOLL 
       WHERE doe between '2014-09-29 00:00:00' 
          AND '2014-09-29 23:59:59' 
          AND CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' 
          AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN' 
       ORDER BY doe
       LIMIT 5 
    ) tmp)
UNION
( .... more sqls here if needed ... )
```

But I assume you want to get the results by day, and if the "**first five rows per day**" is **not** important, you could simply go with selecting summed results grouped by day (which you achieve by `DATE(doe)`):

```
 SELECT ID, VARIABLE, VAR_MEASURE_1, doe, DATE(doe) as date_doe, CONTRACT_CODE, SUM(VAR_MEASURE_1) AS SUMA
 FROM LIVE_VARCOLL 
 WHERE CONTRACT_CODE = 'DEC' 
    AND VARIABLE = 'SBEN' 
 GROUP BY DATE(doe)
 ORDER BY DATE(doe)
```

Comment: This works perfectly,, how do I repeat this multiple times? Like I have in my first query? Do I still use UNION

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, this is perfect, I will use the UNION way with sub query as the first five rows is important.